# Convert Special Character to CodeHex Php

Tags: php

I have to convert the special Character to CodeHex
For Example

```
À => &#xC0;
```

I tried with `html_entity_decode, utf8_encode, htmlentities` But without success.

I have to create a xml file

Comment: Accented characters are all perfectly valid in XML - why convert them at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without questioning if that conversions are really needed / useful: you can first get the [ASCII code](http://php.net/manual/de/function.ord.php) and then [convert it to hex](http://php.net/manual/de/function.dechex.php):

```
echo "&#x".strtoupper(dechex(ord('À'))).";"
```

For echoing the contents in your browser, you can use

```
echo htmlentities("&#x".strtoupper(dechex(ord("À"))).";");
```

Or - depending on your encoding, try using [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.utf8-decode.php) for your input ([test here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d8498883bdc4d6bdd327e95bb7564bd7369cb131)):

```
echo htmlentities("&#x".strtoupper(dechex(ord(utf8_decode("À")))).";");
```

Then, the output will be displayed correctly as `&#xC0;`.

Comment: Of course - it is a html entity which is parsed and displayed as À in the browser - I modified the answer to provide more details.

Comment: yes, sorry for my stupid question...I receive always this code `&#xC3;` with all my special character

Comment: `echo htmlentities("&#x".strtoupper(dechex(ord("À"))).";");` the output is `&#xC3;` no `&#xC0;`

Comment: That will depend on your encoding imho - at least that is what the engine makes out of that character. Please ensure that the input data and the apache header / html doctype is using the correct / same encoding. I edited the answer once again.